# Save WCF service configuration to file

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF service console application. All service settings is hardcoded. I would like to see how this configuration will look in `web.config` file. Actually I need `system.serviceModel` section. How to save my service settings to file?

```
namespace WCF_con
{

    [ServiceContract]
    interface IStringService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Reverse(string s);
    }

    class MyStringService : IStringService
    {
        public string Reverse(string s)
        {
            return new string(s.Reverse().ToArray());
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {


        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/StringService");

            using (ServiceHost serviceHost =
                new ServiceHost(typeof (MyStringService), baseAddress))
            {
                // Check to see if it already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb =
                    serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();

                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy12;
                serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Add MEX endpoint
                serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
                    "mex"
                    );

                serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IStringService), binding, baseAddress);



                serviceHost.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is running. Press any key to stop.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has good topics. Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751418(v=vs.110).aspx